# Building a REST API with ExpressJS and Nodejs - POST and PUT operation issue

Tags: node.js, api, google-chrome, rest, express

I am trying to implement an in-memory REST API using Nodejs and Express4.

I have no problem listing users and getting a user by id. However, I am having troubles with POST operation.

**Edit: As suggested in the comments, I am now using req.body to pass the JSON data that is received in the request, but "null" is added to my array instead of the JSON data. I am not sure if this is a problem in my code or due to the way I use Postman.**

Below is how I am using Postman to send the data **
(I have removed the comma after the last value:)**:
[image]

Below is my code:

**user.js**

```
var users = [{"id": "1", "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe"}];
exports.getAllUser = function() {
  return users;
};

exports.getUserById = function(id) {
  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    if (users[i].id == id) return users[i];
  }
};

exports.deleteUser = function(id) {
  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    if (users[i].id == id) {
        users.splice(i,1);
    }
  }
}

exports.updateUser = function(id, json) {
  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    if (users[i].id == id) {
        users.splice(i, 1, json);
    }
  }
}

exports.addUser = function(json) {
    users.push(json);
}
```

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var users = require('./user');

var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var router = express.Router();

router.use(function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('%s %s', req.method, req.path);
  next();  
});

router.get('/users', function(req, res, next) {
  res.json({ users: users.getAllUser() });
});

router.get('/users/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  var user = users.getUserById(req.params.id)
  res.json(user);
});

router.put('/users/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  users.updateUser(req.params.id, req.body);
});

router.delete('/users/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  users.deleteUser(req.params.id);
});

router.post('/users', function(req, res, next) {
  users.addUser(req.body);
});

// Only requests to /api/ will be send to router.
app.use('/api', router);
app.listen(port);
console.log('Server listening on port ' + port);
```

Regarding the POST, how should I pass the JSON from the request to the array? I guess the answer to that question would also help me with performing a PUT (an update). I would have 2 parameters, one would be the ID, the other would be the JSON data?

Additionally, how to test the POST with Postman? Where do I specify the JSON to send?

Comment: With it being a POST i assume that the json payload is coming in on the body of the http request, have you looked at using body-parser to retrieve that data?

Comment: `req.body` should contain the object that you posted to the server.

Comment: @DavinTryon - I have updated my code to reflect the change you suggested, using req.body to pass the json data that is being sent. However, "null" is added to the array.

Comment: Please show what you are posting to the server.

Comment: @DavinTryon - have updated my initial post with a screenshot.

Comment: Your JSON isn't valid, take away the last comma. After `"Smith"`.

Comment: @DavinTryon - OK. I corrected it. It is still adding null.

Comment: Are you adding the `Content-Type` header in Postman?  `Content-Type: application/json`.  Otherwise all looks good to me.

Comment: This is what is being sent: POST /api/users HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache

{ "id": "10", "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Smith" }

Comment: @DavinTryon -  added a log in my router.post() method. router.post('/users', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("posted data: " + req.body);
  users.addUser(req.body);
}); Which shows me in the console that req.body is undefined.

Comment: @ckross - nope I haven't, can't I just use req.body and pass that data along?

Comment: @ckross - I added app.use(bodyParser.json()); to use body parser and it is now working. Thank you guys :)

Answer (score 0):

When you are sending json in a http body, you should set the correct http Content-Type header, regardless of the http method. In case of json it is 'application/json'. You should add this header in postman.
This header signals that the http body of the received request has a valid json serialized string.
To automatically parse the http body you can use a middleware like https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser . This middleware tries to parse the received http body according to the "Content-Type" header - in your case json. If this express middleware succeeds with parsing the body as json it populates 'req.body' with it.

Comment: May be look into this tool. It help me to get started with nodejs quickly https://codecanyon.net/item/nodejs-automatic-api-generator-from-mysql-database-ultimate-edition/25033454